# How to constrain Interface generic to only string or object or null?

Tags: typescript

```js
export interface Foo<T extends string | object | null> {
  bar: T;
}

type Callback<T = any> = (res: T) => void

function hydra<T extends string | object | null>(callback: Callback<Foo<T>>) {
    callback({
        bar: 'Hello World'
    });
}
```

I doesn't work. It throws this error:

```js
Type '"Hello World"' is not assignable to type 'T'.
  '"Hello World"' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T', but 'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'string | object | null'.
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgMQggB4AVOUVJAEwGc5aYpkBzOAHzggCMArYbPE5IArgBsxAPjgBvAFBw43TFABccUgG45AXzlyYATzB4AwpgnLsAazJwAvHExJD0xwAoowWutIBKB2kANwgEan10ESRBBAgkOC8YESgkACVvSCRaYDtKYBp6RmYkNk4efkEOOFEJSXdsCzEra3VzSxxbQhJSSUkA+UVFBvabdwHBieU1OAByAEkAOQA1AEE5gBkAEQB9VIBRAEUAVT2AZVIZhUGdP209IA)

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: It works here though: [Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIHt0B4AqyIAekIAJgM7JlhSgDmyAPsugEYBWECYjyIArgBsBAPmQBvAFDJpyFnCgAuZDgDcEgL5qJCdCCrICSjNio0QtUQF5xs+UoDkAC2D3km7bv0BPI5iysOLisbOUUbRzhgAQdHLxIoOFd1dx09bgAvX2x+IWCxWzCcgTc1VP0ARyysFkwBCDgQPIKlaj4UdwkCADpQ5Gt7AAkIIXR7NSA)

Comment: There is no error [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIHt0B4AqyIAekIAJgM7JlhSgDmyAPsugEYBWECYjyIArgBsBAPmQBvALAAoZLOQs4UAFzIcAbmkBfadID0u3unxQo6KNIToQVZDEwBGFRmxUaIWqIC846bIXLkAHIACQghIwB1MwESQK0dKVBIWEQUYLhgAWCATxIoOB8ZOQALXPyVFkwBCDgQeKk9AxAjaFNzKUtrbjt0ACYnTCx0zJy8uC9Cv0UVSSLZUrGVaj4IX2RtKU0NBql9Q2M2iysbHoBmAex+IQnZqYCrgXrGg7MjrttMABYLrEr0atqNzW-hUITCAki0ViWjUQA)

Comment: Please consider providing a [mcve] suitable for dropping into a standalone IDE so that others can demonstrate your issue for themselves.  Right now you haven't included the code that gives you the error you're mentioning, so it's unlikely anyone will be able to help you effectively.  Good luck!

Comment: @PoulKruijt Updated the question to show the exact error. Tested in the playground.

Comment: @v.kostenko Updated the question to show the exact error. Tested in the playground.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make a subtype which contains your constraints, and have that declared as the value of `bar`. This way you don't have the constraint issues where `T` could be something else than the provided string:

```
export type FooType = string | object | null;

export interface Foo {
  bar: FooType;
}

type Callback<T = any> = (res: T) => void

function returnResponse(callback: Callback<Foo>) {
  callback({
    bar: 'INVAILD_REQUEST'
  });
}
```

---

This will make your lose your generic type hinting though. So another solution would be to use `as T`.

```
export interface Foo<T extends string | object | null> {
  bar: T;
}

type Callback<T = any> = (res: T) => void

function hydra<T extends string | object | null>(callback: Callback<Foo<T>>) {
  callback({
    bar: 'Hello World' as T
  });
}
```

The reason you have to do that is because if a consumer of the hydra function passes in a callback with a different generic type, your type `string` does not suffice anymore. Like the error message says:

> '"Hello World"' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T', but 'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'string | object | null'.

If you have an error like this, you always need to do a `as T` to make the compiler happy

Answer (score 1):

The main problem here is, although the literal `Hello World` is assignable to a `string`, the fact of having a generic argument (as a constraint) relies on having possibly a subtype of `string` which `Hello World` would not satisfy.

Suppose this scenario

```
type StringSubtype = 'Not Hello World';
hydra<StringSubtype>(res => {
    // ...
});
```

The generic argument of the function `hydra` is now a subset of `string`. And, indeed, it satisfies the `extends string | object | null` constraint. All valid.
But, `res.bar` is of type `'Not Hello World'` which means not other string value can match the type.

```
hydra<StringSubtype>(res => {
    // ...

    // Type '"Hello World"' is not assignable to type '"Not Hello World"'
    res = {
        bar: `Hello World`
    };
});
```

This is what your compilation error says

> Type '"Hello World"' is not assignable to type 'T'.
>     '"Hello World"' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T', but 'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'string | object | null'.

Even if `Hello World` is assignable to `string`, the compiler does not guarantee that `T` could be a subtype of `string`.

**Solution**

Simply don't declare your `hydra` function as generic. Use the more flexible union type as a type argument of `Foo<>` directly.

```
function hydra(callback: Callback<Foo<string | object | null>>) {
    callback({
        bar: 'Hello World'
    });
}
```

**EDIT:** Alternative solutions

1. Force casting `Hello World` as `T`

```
function hydra<T extends string | object | null>(callback: Callback<Foo<T>>) {
    callback({
        bar: 'Hello World' as unknown as T
    });
}
```

2. Union the `T` with the forced value

```
function hydra<T extends string | object | null>(callback: Callback<Foo<T | 'Hello World'>>) {
    callback({
        bar: 'Hello World'
    });
}
```

But, deeply enough, if you are forcing a value to `res.bar`, there's no reason to have any generic argument.
However, your example is a sample and I guess there should be a reason for this... I hope any of these three workarounds matches with your intention.

I explained what the error was, at least. So you can achieve what you need with this knowledge, I guess.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Removing generics from function won't make the function reusable. The only reason I introduced the generic to the system to enforce the type of `bar`.